# Form element names not responding well with MasterPage

Tags: c#, html, code-behind

I'm building some website to manage SQL Server databases and I have an edit page to edit a row of my choice. Problem is when I check for the elements' names, instead of being `name="Name"`, `name="Pass"` etc, it's `name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Name"` and `name=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Pass` because it's using a `MasterPage`.

Is there a way of fixing the names so I can use `Form.Request["Name"]` instead of `Form.Request[this.Name.Name]`? Because gender radio buttons don't return the proper element name so it's not being set when I click the set button.

This is my HTML markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Edit.aspx.cs" Inherits="Edit" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<div dir="rtl" style="text-align:center">
<h1>עדכון נתונים</h1>
    <form runat="server" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<%=Request.QueryString["ID"] %>" />
        <table style="border: 2px solid black; text-align:center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td>שם</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" tabindex="1" runat="server" maxlength="15" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>סיסמא</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Pass" id="Pass" tabindex="2" runat="server" maxlength="25" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>גיל</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Age" id="Age" tabindex="3" runat="server" maxlength="2" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>מין</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="True"  name="Gender" id="Male" tabindex="4" runat="server" />זכר
                    <input type="radio" value="False" name="Gender" id="Female" runat="server" tabindex="5" />נקבה
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="עדכן" name="Send" tabindex="6" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: you can use ClientIDMode="Static", BUT it only works with the id.

Comment: @ViROscar it's not even working for the ID..

Comment: you need to modify the top area of the aspx file:

<%@ Page Title="" Language="" AutoEventWireup="" MasterPageFile="" CodeBehind="" Inherits="" ClientIDMode="Static" %>

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ClientIDMode on your Form to Static

```
<form runat="server" method="post" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Tried that `<form runat="server" method="post" clientidmode="Static">`, but the element's name and id stays the same as before..

Comment: Sorry, try adding the ClientIDMode to your Content element:

    `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Content2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">`

Comment: It works, but the `ID` isn't really my problem. I need the `name` to be static.. Is there a way of doing that like with the `ID`?

Comment: I don't think you force the name to be static:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1863171.aspx?How+to+stop+asp+net+from+changing+the+name+of+a+dynamically+created+radioButton+

Comment: So I will keep using `this.*.Name`, but problem is the radio buttons aren't returning the correct `name` when calling both `this.Male.Name` and `this.Female.Name`..